# How do I get rid of the extra spacing that is appearing at the top of my Android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm building a homepage for an Android app for one of my college classes. My group is using Android Studio. I've got the layout that I was but I have this random extra space at the top above where it says Welcome.

[image: homepage screenshot]

I cannot figure out how to get rid of that random spacing at the top and it's pushing the rest of my objects down (reports list disappears below nav bar)

Here's my fragment_home.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_welcome"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20pt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_appts"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_appts"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/title_appointments"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_appts"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_appts"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_chats"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.484"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_appts"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.226" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_chats"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/title_chats"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_chats"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_appts" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_chats"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_reports"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.484"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_chats"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.226" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_reports"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/title_reports"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_reports"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_chats" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_reports"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.424"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_reports"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.226" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's my HomeFragment.java

```java
package com.example.telemedicine.ui.home;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.telemedicine.R;
import com.example.telemedicine.ui.utilities.RecyclerItem;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView_appt, recyclerView_chat, recyclerView_report;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter_appt, mAdapter_chat, mAdapter_report;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager_appt, layoutManager_chat, layoutManager_report;
    private String[] apptData = {"Physical - 9/29 @ 10:00am", "Vaccination - 10/4 @ 1:30pm", "Check-Up - 10/19 @ 9:00am"};
    private String[] chatData = {"Dr. Jane Smith", "Dr. Hayden Lee", "Dr. Michael Dean"};
    private String[] reportData = {"Blood Work 9/10", "Vaccination Summary 9/1", "Physical 8/23"};
    //Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

        recyclerView_appt = (RecyclerView)root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_appts);
        layoutManager_appt = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView_appt.setLayoutManager(layoutManager_appt);
        mAdapter_appt = new RecyclerItem(apptData);
        recyclerView_appt.setAdapter(mAdapter_appt);

        recyclerView_chat = (RecyclerView)root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_chats);
        layoutManager_chat = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView_chat.setLayoutManager(layoutManager_chat);
        mAdapter_chat = new RecyclerItem(chatData);
        recyclerView_chat.setAdapter(mAdapter_chat);

        recyclerView_report = (RecyclerView)root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_reports);
        layoutManager_report = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView_report.setLayoutManager(layoutManager_report);
        mAdapter_report = new RecyclerItem(reportData);
        recyclerView_report.setAdapter(mAdapter_report);

        return root;
    }
}
```

Here's my HomeViewModel.java

```java
package com.example.telemedicine.ui.home;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

And my activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't know what other files to include but hopefully the problem is in those four files. I've tried so many things to get rid of that spacing, but I cannot figure out how to get rid of it.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I see you have `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` in your activity layout, but you don't have an action bar. Isn't it as simple as just removing that padding?

Comment: Michiel, it was that simple. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `activity_main.xml` file, try removing the `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` line in the ConstraintLayout since there is no actionBar.

Answer (score 2):

in your activity_main.xml change 'fragment' (nav_host_fragment) layout_width and layout_height to 0dp. that is the correct form of using constraints.

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

Comment: Mayokun's solution worked but yours did make a difference. Thanks!!